# Entity Framework DbContext Scope in Window Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, desktop-application, dbcontext

I have gone through many articles but find too less information about the scope of DbContext in window forms applications. So far I have seen following implementations:

1) First Implementation

```
using(var db=new DbContext())
{
   // perform operations
}
```

2) Second Implementation

```
public class A
{
     private DbContext _db;

     public void DoSomething()
     {
         _db.Students.Find(1);
     }
}
```

3) Third Implementation

Using the Singleton class to initialize the DbContext and call it in whole program/Application

4) Fourth Implementation

Declaring the DbContext in a common or settings class as a static property and Call it in whole project/Application.

So, my question is what is the best implementation of DbContext in an application and why ? And what are the drawbacks of other implementations that are not the best ?

Comment: [Below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48833372/3110834) has some valid points. Also read the duplicate post.

Comment: @RezaAghaei that question does not contain any implementations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbContext is a unit-of-work pattern and is designed to be (a) cheap to instantiate and (b) short lived.

You can run into a lot of problems using a long-lived DbContext.  For example, retrieved entities are cached per DbContext so this can happen: [Entity Framework reverts changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979906/entity-framework-reverts-changes/32980310#32980310)

Comment: So this means that I should go with the first implementation but I have seen many experts using the singleton implementation